# Need to convert Xamarin.Forms.Image to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

I am importing image from camera which is being stored as a Xamarin.Forms.Image.

I need to convert this to System.Drawing.Image. Can anyone help me with this?

And also if you can help me on how to assign a .png image to System.Drawing.Image.

For example for a xamarin.forms.image we use`image.Source = "Image1.png";` Any similar code for System.Drawing.Image?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The camera returns a jpg - the Xamarin.Forms.Image is the control used to display it on the screen, not the image itself.  System.Drawing.Image is a w32 construct that doesn't apply to Xamarin.

Comment: Is there no way we can convert the input jpg file to System.Drawing.Image?

Comment: System.Drawing.Image does not exist in Xamarin, it is a Win32 object

Comment: it might be helpful if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, and why you think creating a System.Drawing.Image will help you do it.

Comment: @Michael_B, did you solve this?

Comment: @Jen143, I only edited the question for quality. I didn't attempt to solve the problem. If you want to bring attention to this question, consider posting a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).